# Textmate: jsdoc comment?

Tags: javascript, textmate

I'm pretty new to TextMate and I just can't figure out how to make JSDoc like comment when editing .js file. I'm using the PHP bundle and there it is pretty easy - I just type doc and then tab. I've already added custom snippet but the problem is that it does not handle new lines properly (it doesn't insert trailing *).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install a JSDoc bundle, but it doesn't look like there's much available. A quick google search did bring up something though: https://github.com/tysontate/javascript-jsdoc-tmbundle

No idea if it's any good, and it actually says that the commands don't yet work, but it appears to have seen at least some activity lately (unlike the others I found). It looks like there just aren't that many people who are using JS Doc (or, at least not that many TextMate users who are using it).

Usually, googling for "*something* bundle textmate" will yield the right results, but apparently JSDoc just isn't that commonly used.

However, maybe someone has added some JSDoc functionality to the existing JavaScript bundle (much like you've started doing). Didn't try looking for that, but you might get lucky.

But hey, it's a good excuse to get your hands dirty (and learn *a lot* about TextMate in the process) by messing around with whatever the available bundles have to offer, maybe even fixing a few bugs, and giving something back to the community (you don't have to of course, it's just a suggestion).

Not much of an answer, but hopefully you'll find our way from here

Comment: Thank you! I'm not so sure how I missed that bundle but it looks awesome.

Answer (score 1):

An updated bundle with tools for editing JSDoc comments in TextMate 2 is available at https://github.com/rootworkit/JsDoc-Toolkit.tmbundle